# Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl

Tags: php, email, imap

This is my PHP code to list emails from Gmail and I have also enabled IMAP in php.ini and in gmail. but I am keep getting the following error, what am I doing wrong?

///

Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in C:\xampp7\htdocs\inbox\gmail\index.php on line 62
Cannot connect to Gmail: Too many login failures
Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
///

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('imap_open')) {
    echo "IMAP is not configured.";
    exit();
} else {
    ?>
<div id="listData" class="list-form-container">
        <?php
    
    /* Connecting Gmail server with IMAP */
    $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'gmail username', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* Search Emails having the specified keyword in the email subject */
    $emailData = imap_search($connection, 'SUBJECT "Article "');
    
    if (! empty($emailData)) {
        ?>
        <table>
        <?php
        foreach ($emailData as $emailIdent) {
            
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($connection, $emailIdent, 0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($connection, $emailIdent, '1.1');
            $messageExcerpt = substr($message, 0, 150);
            $partialMessage = trim(quoted_printable_decode($messageExcerpt)); 
            $date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($overview[0]->date));
            ?>
            <tr>
                    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="column"><?php echo $overview[0]->from; ?></span></td>
                    <td class="content-div"><span class="column"><?php echo $overview[0]->subject; ?> - <?php echo $partialMessage; ?></span><span class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        } // End foreach
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
    } // end if
    
    imap_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your login and password are correct?

Comment: @lot yes i have double checked it, its fine

Comment: Have you turned on less secure apps and/or generated an App Specific Password?  Plain vanilla authentication is generally not permitted by gmail anymore.

Comment: @Max so what should i do

Comment: Go into your account settings and turn on "less secure apps" or generate an App Specific Password, depending on your other account settings.  ASPs are more secure if they're available to your account, but I think they require Two-Factor-Auth to be turned on.